# MySQL won't start in MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

I can't start MySQL in MAMP. This is the error in the log.

```
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
```

However, if I run `mysql_upgrade` I get

```
mysql_upgrade: command not found
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command;

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force

It looks like the Path to MAMP bin directory is not in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns `Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed`

Comment: Try adding innodb_force_recovery = 1 to your my.cnf file and then restart MySQL. If it starts ok, remove this line so it doesn't try recovery on next start/restart.